# Show spinner (preloader/loading indicator) whenever page changes and hide when all assets are loaded in Vue Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, gridsome

I am using Gridsome (Vue static site generator with Vue Router) and I've created a preloader in [index.html](https://gridsome.org/docs/overriding-index/), its a simple div that covers everything. In index.html I also added this JS code to hide the preloader when everything loads

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
};
```

This works only for the initial load, but when changing pages I am having trouble showing it and hiding it again.

I've tried to add this to my `Layout` component's `beforeDestroy()` hook to show the preloader again

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.preloader.style.display = 'block';
}
```

which shows it successfully when the route is changed, but then if I add the hiding logic in `mounted()` like this

```
mounted() {
  this.preloader.style.display = 'none';
}
```

the preloader is never showed in the first place.

I was unable to find any resources about this kind of loading indicators, all I can find are one's for async calls like `axios` or `fetch`. I've created preloaders before in static HTML files, but never in SPAs. Can someone please push me in the right direction? Even googling keywords will help

Comment: How about using vuex? [Client API \- Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/docs/client-api/#appoptions)

Comment: @nabeen would you be kind enough to elaborate on this idea please?

Comment: i showed vuex example code. check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vuex with this case.

first, add your state `src/main.js`

```js
import DefaultLayout from "~/layouts/Default.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

export default function(Vue, { appOptions }) {
  Vue.component("Layout", DefaultLayout);
  Vue.use(Vuex);

  appOptions.store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      loading: false,
    },
    mutations: {
      on(state) {
        state.loading = true;
      },
      off(state) {
        state.loading = false;
      },
    },
  });
}
```

second, add spinner to `./src/layouts/Default.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="layout">
    // add your spinner here or another
    <div v-if="$store.state.loading">loading</div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

finally, add commit code pages, templete, or components. like below.

```
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    // commit("on") first
    this.$store.commit("on");

    // commit("off") last, after fetch data or more.
    this.$store.commit("off");
  },
};
</script>
```